# Create files in different folders changing at each loop

Tags: loops, fortran, filenames, directory

I have a loop and each time I write a file in the main directory, whose name changes with loop variable. E.g. for the loop

```
do i=1,10
```

I create and write data in the files `test1.out, test2.out, ..., test10.out`.

What I want to do now is this: I want to have a second loop (e.g. `do j=1,5`) and store the files above at 5 different folders, already existing inside the main directory. The truth is that for each `j`, the content of the files testi.out is changing, so I want to gather them in specific folders.

A sample of my current code is:

```
do i=1,10

  write(name, 14) 'test',iw,'.out'

  open(unit=70, file=name)

  write(70,*) 0.0

enddo

14  format (a10,i1,a4)
```

When I write the second line as follows:

```
write(name, 14) 'folder1/test',iw,'.out'
```

then it creates the files in the `folder1`. I want this inside an other `loop (j=1,5)`, so each time the files are created in the folders `folder1, folder2, ..., folder5`.

Any ideas for this?

Comment: I don't understand what is preventing you writing that outer loop yourself.  It seems to me that you've managed to figure out how to write a variation on the file name at each iteration of the `i` loop, what's stopping you writing the `j` loop for yourself ?

Comment: The problem is that I want an extra variation on the folder name at each iteration of j loop.

Comment: The "end" in the code above should be "end do".

Comment: You are right Fortranner!

Answer (score 1):

Hint (for `i=1,9`):

```
write(name, 14) 'folder',j,'/test',i,'.out'
```

Note: Check your `format` statement for `i=10`. You need different `FORMAT` magic (`i0`)!

Note2: On Windows, `\\` can be used instead

Comment: No, OP doesn't need `trim` or `adjustl`, OP needs `i0` edit descriptor.

Comment: The '/' before the filename (test) creates an error.It says: "severe<29>: file not found, unit 70, file...folder1\test1.out". When I remove the slash, it creates a file with name: 'folder1   test1.out', having corrected the FORMAT statement, as you mention.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thanks, that is indeed simpler approach. What do you mean by "OP"?

Comment: @Antigoni Are you on windows? Use `/` slash or alternatively '\\' for win

Comment: Many thanks!! I solved my problem!! I'm on windows and I was using /.

Comment: If your problem is solved, do not forget to mark answer